# Techniques for upper bounding square of sum of square roots?

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics, number-theory, inequality, approximation

Say I have $x_1,...,x_n$ such that $0 \leq x_i \leq 1$ for all $i \in n$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i = 1$. Let $\epsilon > 0$ be some small number. Let $y_1,...,y_n$ be $\epsilon$-close approximations of $x_i,...,x_n$; specifically, $\lvert y_i - x_i\rvert < \epsilon$ for all $i \in n$. Further, $\sum_{i=1}^ny_i=1$ and $0 \leq y_i \leq 1$ for all $i \in n$.

How can we upper bound in terms of $n$ and $\epsilon$ for the following:
$$
\Bigg[1 - \bigg( \sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{x_iy_i} \bigg)^2\Bigg]^{1/2}
$$

EDIT:

It's clear (thanks to @RobertIsrael, see below) that if $\epsilon > 2/n$, then the trivial upper bound of $1$ cannot be beat. What is the bound if $0 < \epsilon < 1/n$?

Comment: Do you want to assume $x_i \ge \epsilon$ now?

Comment: ah I see your point, let me update once more. thank you for the help

Comment: The question, even in the new form you've given it, it is subject to the very same objection pointed out by @RobertIsrael: if we let for example $y_i=x_i+\epsilon/2$ then again $\big(\sum \sqrt{x_iy_i}\big)^2$ is strictly greater than $1$.

Comment: @DanieleTampieri You cant do that because y_i add to 1

Comment: Mmm, you're right @SandeepSilwal: my example is not correct. However there is something which does non convince me.

Comment: i *think* it's well-formed question now. the expression will be very close to zero and we can upper bound it in terms of $n$ and $\epsilon$. i'm very interested in the techniques used to accomplish this

Comment: @jjaylon So we are assuming y_i is also non negative?

Comment: @SandeepSilwal yes! sorry again, i just updated the question to reflect this. and thanks again to all that have taken the time to read this.

Answer (score 2):

You can't, because it won't be real.
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{(x_i+\epsilon) x_i} > \sum_{i=1}^n x_i = 1$$
so you're taking the square root of a negative number.

Perhaps you meant
$$ \left[ \left(\sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{(x_i+\epsilon) x_i}\right)^2 - 1\right]^{1/2} $$

EDIT:  OK, for the new question, let
$$ Q = \left[ 1 - \left(\sum_{i} \sqrt{x_i y_i}\right)^2\right]^{1/2}$$

You want an upper bound $Q \le U$, presumably better than the trivial $U=1$, which amounts to a lower bound

$$ \sum_{i} \sqrt{x_i y_i} \ge \sqrt{1-U^2} > 0$$

But this won't necessarily be possible.  Suppose $n$ is even and $\epsilon > 2/n$,  take $x_i = 0$ and $y_i = 2/n$ for $i \le n/2$,
$x_i = 2/n$ and $y_i = 0$ for $i > n/2$.  Then all $\sqrt{x_i y_i} = 0$ and $Q = 1$.